# Creating KalViewController object using ARC?

Tags: xcode

I successfully installed & linked the static library of Kal Calendar.  However, I'm struggling with creating a calendar object without using alloc & autorelease under ARC environment. I tried to turn off the ARC option by using "-fno-objc-arc" thing... but it gives me 'Apple Mach-O Linker (Id) Error'

Did anyone succeed to use it with ARC and storyboard?  :'(

Edited:  This is the error msg I got.

Ld Test.app/Test normal i386
    cd /Users/Phrixus/Desktop/Test
    setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
    setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk -L/Users/Phrixus/Desktop/Test -F/Users/Phrixus/Desktop/Test -filelist /Users/Phrixus/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Test-cwrxnjyllxlrlmczaymhzykteqlq/Build/Intermediates/Test.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Test.build/Objects-normal/i386/Test.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -Objc -all_load -fobjc-arc -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=50000 -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -o /Users/Phrixus/Desktop/Test/Test.app/Test

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_KalViewController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in CalendarViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: a `Apple Mach-O Linker (Id) Error'` is a potentially broad error... did the build log give any more info than that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I suspected, this isn't an ARC problem.

You're building for the simulator but the library you're attempting to link to is for the device.

Either A) Figure out how to build and install a simulator-compatible version of KalViewController and link against it.

or B)

Make sure the library is truly included.  In other words, is the libKal.a target checkbox checked? I did a bit of Googling for you and [found somebody else who appears to have solved the same problem that you have](https://github.com/klazuka/Kal/issues/10).

Comment: OH MY GOD!! you're absolutely correct!  It was unchecked >:(.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have to include libKal.a as a static library if having problems installing it or simply choose not to add it as a static library. 
You could create a new group in your project and add all the .h and .m files from Kal (and the Kal.bundle).
You will have errors compiling if you're using ARC, but you can go to "Compile Sources" under "Build Phases" and add the option -fno-objc-arc for the Kal files.
This way you can use the Kal library with ARC.