# Undefined symbols for architecture i386 using protobuf

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4, protocol-buffers, i386

I'm trying to make an app that uses Protocol Buffers. I'm getting this error, any idea why?

```
Ld /Users/fmota/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PBTest-gvudadeakgzklbekugyiqyfyprlt/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PBTest.app/PBTest normal i386
cd /Users/fmota/Documents/Developer/Protobuf/PBTest
setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk -L/Users/fmota/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PBTest-gvudadeakgzklbekugyiqyfyprlt/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/fmota/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PBTest-gvudadeakgzklbekugyiqyfyprlt/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/fmota/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PBTest-gvudadeakgzklbekugyiqyfyprlt/Build/Intermediates/PBTest.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PBTest.build/Objects-normal/i386/PBTest.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=50000 -framework SystemConfiguration -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -o /Users/fmota/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PBTest-gvudadeakgzklbekugyiqyfyprlt/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PBTest.app/PBTest

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AreaRequest_Builder", referenced from:
       objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a common problem I've seen.

Check out the answer to [this nearly duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8719547/creating-kalviewcontroller-object-using-arc) and let me know if it solves the issue for you. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Add *.pb.h and *.pb.m to "TARGET"->"Build Phases"->"Compile Sources"!

Answer (score 0):

My working env is xcode 5.0.2.

Add *.pb.m to "TARGET"->"Build Phases"->"Compile Sources"

Do NOT add *.pb.h, after I added *.pb.h, it cannot link.